# row-fluid is stacking columns

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm an experienced software engineer just getting into web dev and I'm having some issues getting bootstrap 3 row-fluid to work correctly.  Basically, I'm trying to get a side navigation bar and an angular application to work together in a fluid layout, but when I attempt to use row-fluid, it is stacking the two elements instead of putting them side by side.  Here is the code:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row-fluid">
    <div class="span3 bs-docs-sidebar">
      <ul class="nav nav-list bs-docs-sidenav">
        <li class="nav-header">Administer</li>
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Users</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Devices</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="span9">
      <div ng-view></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Also interesting is if I change row-fluid to row, the same behavior persists.  Changing spanX to col-lg-X fixes it, but I lose the fluid layout.  any ideas?

Comment: Is there anything in class bs-docs-sidebar that might be affecting layout?

Comment: Those are Bootstrap 2.3's classes you're using here. Not Bootstrap 3

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap 3 is responsive by default, so there is no need for the `-fluid`. you can just use `row` and `container`.

And the `span` classes you are using are from bootstrap 2.x not 3. you need to use something like `col-lg-4` or `col-xs-4`. check out the bootstrap 3 docs for more info on this.

[See here for more info on the Bootstrap 3 grid system](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid)

Answer (score 0):

Use .col-md-* instead of .span*